# How to prepare imagenet dataset to run resnet50 (from official Tensorflow Model Garden) training

Tags: tensorflow, imagenet, tensorflow-model-garden

I'd like to train a resnet50 model on imagenet2012 dataset on my local GPU server, following exactly this Tensorflow official page: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/image_classification#imagenet-preparation
However, I don't know how to prepare the imagenet2012 training and validation dataset exactly such that I can start the training like this:

```
python3 classifier_trainer.py \
  --mode=train_and_eval \
  --model_type=resnet \
  --dataset=imagenet \
  --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR \
  --data_dir=$DATA_DIR ??? \ # ----------> HOW TO CONFIG THIS DIR IF I HAVE DOWNLOADED THE DATA??
  --config_file=configs/examples/resnet/imagenet/gpu.yaml \
  --params_override='runtime.num_gpus=$NUM_GPUS'
```

Specifically, I **have downloaded** the dataset as two tar files:`ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar`,`ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar` to `\myPath` directory, following the instruction:https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/docs/catalog/imagenet2012.md#imagenet2012
**Could anyone tell me the exact steps to prepare the dataset and setup the configurations** (either via command line arguments or setting in configs/examples/resnet/imagenet/gpu.yaml ).

PS1, I notice there are two types of dataset that can be used by the training script: 1) [using TFDS](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/image_classification#using-tfds) 2) [using TFRecords](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/image_classification#legacy-tfrecords). I have created the TFRecords dataset using the shell script on the bottom of the [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/tools/datasets#imagenet_to_gcspy), but still don't know how to setup the configuration. It seems TFDS is recommended by TF, but I am ok with TFRecords format as long as I can run the training successfully. Currently, I already have training and validation TFRecords files in the following form:

```
${DATA_DIR}/train/train-00000-of-01024
${DATA_DIR}/train/train-00001-of-01024
 ...
${DATA_DIR}/train/train-01023-of-01024

${DATA_DIR}/validation/validation-00000-of-00128
S{DATA_DIR}/validation/validation-00001-of-00128
 ...
${DATA_DIR}/validation/validation-00127-of-00128
```

PS2: Hope the TF community can provide a clear step by step guide of preparing imagenet dataset for a beginner like me. It will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you able to get the output of for:

```
python imagenet_to_gcs.py \
  --raw_data_dir=$IMAGENET_HOME \
  --local_scratch_dir=$IMAGENET_HOME/tf_records \
  --nogcs_upload
```

in the following format?

```
${DATA_DIR}/train-00000-of-01024
${DATA_DIR}/train-00001-of-01024
 ...
${DATA_DIR}/train-01023-of-01024

${DATA_DIR}/validation-00000-of-00128
S{DATA_DIR}/validation-00001-of-00128
 ...
${DATA_DIR}/validation-00127-of-00128
```

I have read a lot of articles performing the task you wish to accomplish and they have followed similar steps as you did but I could not find what got you stuck. If there is any other information you could provide like the error you are getting or something, maybe I could better understand the issue?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have the training data files and validation data files as shown in your answer. However, they are under **two different folders**. I can move all `train-xxx--of--xxx` and `validation--xxx--xxx` to the same folder/${DATA_DIR}. The problem is I don't know how to config the training. I guess I should specify `--data_dir=$DATA_DIR`, right? Do I need to change any anything in `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/image_classification/configs/examples/resnet/imagenet/gpu.yaml` or just use the default configs.

Comment: Yeah, move train and validation folders under DATA_DIR and then set that as the path for `--data_dir`. You can use the default settings for yaml file. It should work as it specifies the basic training configuration.

Comment: I encountered the same problem asked in the question, and this answer was useful to find a final solution. Right now, a code refactoring is in process so `classifier_trainer.py` is not being used anymore, I got my experiment running using: `python3 train.py --experiment=resnet_imagenet --config_file=imagenet_resnet50_gpu_custom.yaml --mode=train_and_eval --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR --params_override='runtime.num_gpus=1'` available in the `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/beta` repository.